# Godot: How do I edit the exe icons of other sizes

Tags: godot, export, filesystem

I asked this question on  Godot Q & A:

https://godotengine.org/qa/53521/godot-program-icons

Basically, my problem is that I want My executable file's icon to display my own custom icon instead of the default Godot icon. I learned that Windows executables come in bundles and now know that I should include icons of other sizes instead of just one.

How do I do this?

**EDIT**

My problem is how I do this in Godot, not having found a means to edit the bundles in Godot.

Comment: This is more a question about `.ico` files than Godot itself, and I believe it has an answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/491180/how-do-i-embed-multiple-sizes-in-an-ico-file

Comment: @rcorre I want to know how to use Godot to accomplish this or is it not possible.

Comment: The point is you _don't_ use Godot to accomplish this. You use another program like ImageMagick (as mentioned in the superuser question) to create the .ico file, and then just put that single `.ico` file in the Godot export settings for Windows.